# str_replace with user input PHP

Tags: java, php, soap, client

i want to delete all the vowels on a user input string, im using str_replace like this

```
$vocales = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"," ");
    $resultado = str_replace($vocales, "", $mensaje);

    
    return $resultado;
```

on soapui works fine but on a java client it just show one word for example if the user input is "hello world" the output is "hll"

this is the java client

```
Consonante servidor = new Consonante();
        ConsonantePortType puerto = servidor.getConsonantePort();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ingresa una palabra");
        String a = sc.next();

        String respuesta = puerto.devolverConsonante(a);
        System.out.println(respuesta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next(), which reads only up to the next whitespace.

Comment: omg how i not see something that basic